# Average per day over period

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is a clear way to calculate an average per day over a period?

For example, suppose I have the table `all_my_logs`:

```
+----+-------+------------------+
| id | count |  timeOf_action*  |
+----+-------+------------------+
|  1 |     5 | day   1, 10:00AM |
|  2 |     0 | day  50, 12:00PM |
|  3 |    10 | day 100, 10:00AM |
|  4 |    12 | day 100, 11:00PM |
+----+-------+------------------+
```

I want the value Average/Day = (5+10+12)/(100-1) = 27/99 = 0.272727

What is a more clear way than

```
SELECT SUM(count) /
DATEDIFF(day,
    (SELECT timeOf_action FROM all_my_logs ORDER by timeOf_action DESC LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT timeOf_action FROM all_my_logs ORDER by timeOf_action ASC  LIMIT 1)
) as AvgPerDayOverPeriod FROM all_my_logs;
```

---

- `timeOf_action` field is `DATETIME`. I use human-readable format to easily see where `100-1` comes from.

Comment: Your code is definitely not MySQL, so I removed that tag.  It looks like SQL Server, so I added that one.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can you enlighten me on why you say it is definitely not MySQL?

Comment: `datediff(day, . . . )`.

Comment: But `LIMIT 1` is not T-SQL @GordonLinoff , which *does* imply MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select sum(count) / ( max(date(timeofaction)) - min(date(timeofaction)) + 1)
from all_my_logs;
```

Or in SQL Server:

```
select sum(count) / (datediff(day, min(timeofaction), max(timeofaction)) + 1)
from all_my_logs;
```

You don't include the `+ 1` in your logic, but I think it is correct for the average you want to calculate.